# How to set the expandable and collapsible tableview cells to be expandable when loading

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, expandablelistview

Im working on a project in swift 3.0 and I wants to set the UITabeViewCells to be expanded when its loading for the first time.So far I have managed to create UITableViewCells to expand once a row is selected. the code as bellow.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

  var destinationData: [HeaderData?]?

    @IBOutlet weak var expandableTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        destinationData = getData()

    }
    private func getData() -> [HeaderData?] {
      //  let data: [HeaderData?] = []

        let freeGiftsList = [ContainerData(mp3Title: "MP3Title", category: "Category",teaserDescription:"TeaserDescription")]
        let freeGifts = HeaderData(name: "Free Gifts", imageName: "header1", expcell: freeGiftsList)

        let exclusiveOffersList = [ContainerData(mp3Title: "MP3Title", category: "Category",teaserDescription:"TeaserDescription")]
        let exclusiveOffers = HeaderData(name: "Exclusive Offers", imageName: "header2", expcell: exclusiveOffersList)

        let allAudiosAndPackagesList = [ContainerData(mp3Title: "MP3Title", category: "Category",teaserDescription:"TeaserDescription")]
        let allAudiosAndPackages = HeaderData(name: "All Audios & Packages", imageName: "header3", expcell: allAudiosAndPackagesList)

        return [freeGifts, exclusiveOffers, allAudiosAndPackages]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()



    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let data = destinationData {
            return data.count
        } else {
            return 0
        }

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let rowData = destinationData?[indexPath.row] {
            let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! HeaderTableViewCell
            headerCell.headerNameLabel.text = rowData.name
            headerCell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: rowData.imageName))
            headerCell.selectionStyle = .none
            return headerCell
        }
            // Row is ExpansionCell
        else {
            if let rowData = destinationData?[getParentCellIndex(expansionIndex: indexPath.row)] {
                //  Create an ExpansionCell
                let expansionCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExpCell", for: indexPath) as! ExpandableTableViewCell

                //  Get the index of the parent Cell (containing the data)
                let parentCellIndex = getParentCellIndex(expansionIndex: indexPath.row)

                //  Get the index of the flight data (e.g. if there are multiple ExpansionCells
                let expIndex = indexPath.row - parentCellIndex - 1

                //  Set the cell's data
                expansionCell.categoryLabel.text = rowData.expOffers?[expIndex].category
                expansionCell.mp3TitleLabel.text = rowData.expOffers?[expIndex].mp3Title
                expansionCell.teaserDescription.text = rowData.expOffers?[expIndex].teaserDescription

                expansionCell.selectionStyle = .none
                return expansionCell
            }
        }
        return UITableViewCell()

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (destinationData?[indexPath.row]) != nil {

            // If user clicked last cell, do not try to access cell+1 (out of range)
            if(indexPath.row + 1 >= (destinationData?.count)!) {
                expandCell(tableView: tableView, index: indexPath.row)
            }
            else {
                // If next cell is not nil, then cell is not expanded
                if(destinationData?[indexPath.row+1] != nil) {
                    expandCell(tableView: tableView, index: indexPath.row)
                    // Close Cell (remove ExpansionCells)
                } else {
                    contractCell(tableView: tableView, index: indexPath.row)

                }
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if (destinationData?[indexPath.row]) != nil {
            return 40
        } else {
            return 100
        }
    }



    /*  Expand cell at given index  */
    private func expandCell(tableView: UITableView, index: Int) {
        // Expand Cell (add ExpansionCells
        if let flights = destinationData?[index]?.expOffers {
            for i in 1...flights.count {
                destinationData?.insert(nil, at: index + i)
                tableView.insertRows(at: [NSIndexPath(row: index + i, section: 0) as IndexPath] , with: .top)
            }
        }
    }

    /*  Contract cell at given index    */
    private func contractCell(tableView: UITableView, index: Int) {
        if let flights = destinationData?[index]?.expOffers {
            for _ in 1...flights.count {
                destinationData?.remove(at: index+1)
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [NSIndexPath(row: index+1, section: 0) as IndexPath], with: .top)

            }
        }
    }

    /*  Get parent cell index for selected ExpansionCell  */
    private func getParentCellIndex(expansionIndex: Int) -> Int {

        var selectedCell: HeaderData?
        var selectedCellIndex = expansionIndex

        while(selectedCell == nil && selectedCellIndex >= 0) {
            selectedCellIndex -= 1
            selectedCell = destinationData?[selectedCellIndex]
        }

        return selectedCellIndex
    }



}
```

Comment: Easily you can create your own implementation: when user selects any cell, insert new data in your data source at required indexes and animate insertion using insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: method.

Comment: would you be kind enough to be more specific in terms of code

Answer (score 1):

My application has expansion in the listing in 4 screens
What i have set is

(1) I Used table-view's section View as my normal listing view

(2) In tap on button on section view I set rows for that section and reload that section.

(3) Again taping on section button reset rows to 0.

=> This is the best and simplest way to achieve expandable view, without customizing table view and default animation like card is expand/collapse.

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.arrMainList.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if (self.arrIndexPathSelectedRow.contains(section)) {
            let objItem = self.arrExpandedList[section] as! myObj
            let myJournals = JournalOperationModel.sharedInstance.getGroupedJournalList(objItem)
            return myJournals.count
        }
        else{
            return 0
        }
    }
```

I have another array named '**arrIndexPathSelectedRow**' will will use to determine either to expand or collapse the card.

And implement IU and other delegate/data source methods

Here are the methods i have used
[image]

Comment: You can follow this approach, let me know if you face any difficulties.